# Angular: How to override nested href with routerLink?

Tags: angular, routerlink, angular-routerlink

I have a third-party package that is using an **href** attribute on a nested anchor tag. Of course, I don't want to navigate using **href**. I applied a **routerLink** directive on the parent because I have no way of accessing and modifying the child component. But the **href** attribute overrides everything. How can I force angular to use the **routerLink** directive?

My code looks like this:

```
<ngx-gallery routerLink="home" [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>
```

Comment: if it can not be configured on the gallery component then the only option is to catch click, keyup, and maybe some other events on the parent on a capturing event phase and stop propagation of that event

Comment: Why the keyup or other events?

Comment: because these events also cause navigation when <a href="..."> is in focus

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First of all, in the source code and documentation from `ngx-gallery` I can't find any reference of an anchor tag being set, but if you say there is, I should believe you.</strike>

You can however try to manually remove the `href` value from the anchor tag. You can even write a separate directive for it:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[disableLinks]'
})
export class DisableLinksDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
    @Optional() @Self() private gallery: NgxGalleryComponent
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.gallery) {
      merge(
        this.gallery.imagesReady,
        this.gallery.change,
        this.gallery.previewChange
      ).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      ).subscribe(() => this.disableLinks())
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.disableLinks();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  private disableLinks(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => a.href = '');
  }
}
```

Which you can then set on your element:

```
<ngx-gallery
  disableLinks
  routerLink="home"
  [options]="galleryOptions"
  [images]="galleryImages">
</ngx-gallery>
```

I don't exactly know if any of those events will trigger the href to be updated again, but that's for you to find out :)

Comment: Regarding the anchor tag here is an issue: https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery/issues/70

Comment: @NebexElias Aha :D It seems like I was wrong. it's inside the thumbnail image. I understand now. I can update my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Why did the person who implemented the package use href though?